# Nginx duplicate post request

Tags: spring-boot, nginx, kubernetes, load-balancing

I have an API using the Spring Boot framework and Nginx as load balance.
Many times in the micro service logs the same request appears more than once, without the client having made the request.
I make a request to another API, it happens when this API takes a long time to respond.

My logs:

```
@timestamp,@message
2019-11-12 13:23:39.545,"{""message"":""{\""timestamp\"":\""2019-11-12 10:23:38\"", \""service\””:\””registration-service-api\””, \""thread\"":\""[qtp812586739-408]\"", \""level\"":\""INFO\"", \""meta\"": Registration 7865 completed””}”
2019-11-12 13:23:26.534,"{""message"":""{\""timestamp\"":\""2019-11-12 10:23:26\"", \""service\"":\""registration-service-api\"", \""thread\"":\""[qtp812586739-506]\"", \""level\"":\""INFO\"", \""meta\"": Registration 7865 completed}””}”
2019-11-12 13:23:25.545,"{""message"":""{\""timestamp\"":\""2019-11-12 10:23:25\"", \""service\"":\""registration-service-api\"", \""thread\"":\""[qtp812586739-408]\"", \""level\"":\""INFO\"", \""meta\"": Registration 7865 started}””}”
2019-11-12 13:23:10.545,"{""message"":""{\""timestamp\"":\""2019-11-12 10:23:10\"", \""service\"":\""registration-service-api\"", \""thread\"":\""[qtp812586739-506]\"", \""level\"":\""INFO\"", \""meta\””:Registration 7865 started}””}”
```

Can you help me? Please.

Comment: Are you using multiple pods in your ingress controller? if yes sometimes multiple ingress pods  takes your API calls. When your api taking more time to respond means you can increase ingress controller pod resources and see if it helps.

Comment: @kishorebjv I'm not sure that is correct. Have you got a source for that behavior?

Comment: Can you provide your nginx logs using `kubectl logs -n <namespace><nginx ingress controller name>` and  your nginx config using `kubectl exec -it -n <namespace-of-ingress-controller> <nginx ingress controller name> cat /etc/nginx/nginx.conf`